# How can I remove an enum label from pg_enum table in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, express, enums, database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I have a Node app (Express) that I built recently, which uses Sequelize to connect to a PostgreSQL instance. I just deployed this to GCP and used Cloud SQL to set up the database. This works quite well and the app properly connects to the DB instance.

However, when running the migrations I have I get this error: `permission denied for table pg_enum`

This happens on a single migration that I have which tries to remove an enum value from the database:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      `DELETE FROM pg_enum WHERE enumlabel = 'to' AND enumtypid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'enum_Subscriptions_emailType')`
    ),

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.sequelize.query(`ALTER TYPE "enum_Subscriptions_emailType" ADD VALUE 'to';`)
}
```

I've read [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#managing-your-instances) that since Cloud SQL is a managed service, it doesn't provide superuser privileges to customers like me. Is there some other way that I can get this migration run?

I've also tried running a Cloud Build process, but that also fails with the following error: `ERROR: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/<project-id>:<project-region>:<db-instance>/.s.PGSQL.5432`. For reference, my `cloudbuild.yaml` file looked like this:

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  args: ['migrate']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

and my package.json scripts were:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "migrate": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "dev": "set DEBUG=app:* && nodemon index.js",
    "deploy": "gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml ."
  }
```

What else can I do to get around this, so that the migrations I have following this one can run and my app can function?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support dropping individual values from enums. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html

If you really need to do this, you can change the type in all columns you use the enum to text, delete the type, recreate the type without the value and change the columns back.

Comment: Thanks Johannes - but this is a change I made a few months ago and it worked quite well on my local postgres database. But it seems to be giving me issues on Cloud SQL - any ideas on what I can do? I actually have 18 more migrations to run after this one (coincidentally, one of these future migrations actually removes the enums altogether)

Comment: it *works* locally, but it's not  officially supported by postgres. Modifying tthe system catalogue always has a risk - which is why it takes superuuser priviliges to do so. W possible workflow to remove the enaum value is already in my first comment: re-create the type. A shorter way is to create a new type first without the value you want to get rid of using a different name, then change all colums, then rename the type.

Comment: I will go a step further than @JohannesH. Directly modifying the system catalog, even by superuser, is a dismiss-able offense. If the system provided commands cannot accomplish the task (and deleting an enum entry is one that has no a alter command) then you take the long way around.  As suggested just delete the the current type, yes you will need to change every reference. Another option would be just leave the value in the enum, but create a trigger disallowing the value.

Comment: Thanks JohannesH. and Belayer - I did not know that modifying these were that bad; will keep this in mind. As JohannesH. has suggested in his answer, I'll comment out this one migration, as we do delete the enum in a future migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing a value from an enum is not supported by PostgreSQL. You can only add new ones or rename existing ones.

While it might work somewhat reliably by modifying the system catalogue, even this is not officially supported and needs superuser permissions for a reason - so there is no way to do it without.

The supported way to do what you want to do is to recreate the type without the value.

```
CREATE TYPE new_enum AS ENUM('a','b','c');

ALTER TABLE table_using_old_enum
    ALTER COLUMN colum_using_old_enum
    SET DATA TYPE new_enum
        USING colum_using_old_enum::text::new_enum;

DROP TYPE old_enum;

ALTER TYPE new_enum RENAME TO old_enum;
```

This obviously only works if no entry in `table_using_old_type` is still set to the value that you want to remove - you need to ensure this first, otherwise the typecast in the `USING` clause will fail for those values.

--

Alternatively, you could also just comment out that query - if you already know that a few minutes later with a later migration the type will be removed completely, it shouldn't cause an issue if that value stays in until then.

Comment: This does *not* work reliably at all. If the removed enum value happens to be used anywhere in the database, you end up with data corruption. I would shun any "migration" tool that does that.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesH. - I ended up commenting out the offending migration and returning a simple Promise instead (since Sequelize, my ORM, requires a promise to be returned in the migration) - since I delete the entire enum later and replace it with a reference table, this results in no issues for me :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe There is no solution that can handle the case of the value-to-be-removed still being used anywhere. Which is why such removal is not supported by PostreSQL. However there is means to check for this case first in a transaction and only continue if no such case is present.